# I want to implement a timer for a game java?

Tags: java, timer

I want to have a method `startTimer(30)` where the parameter is the amount of seconds to countdown.  How do I do so in Java?

Comment: What exactly do you want the method to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java 5 way of doing this would be something like:

```
void startTimer(int delaySeconds) {
  Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(
    runnable,
    delaySeconds,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The `runnable` describes what you want to do. For example:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`java.util.Timer` is not a bad choice, but [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) may be more convenient, as seen in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373625).

Comment: Unless this is a game played from the command line (do people still *make* those?) a Swing `Timer` would seem an obvious choice.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerDemo {
  Toolkit toolkit;

  Timer timer;

  public TimerDemo(int seconds) {
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
  }

  class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("Time's up!");
      toolkit.beep();
      System.exit(0); 
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("About to schedule task.");
    new TimerDemo(30);
    System.out.println("Task scheduled.");
  }
}
```

Many helpful links out there.

- [java timer for game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427626/java-timer-for-game)
- [How to solve this Timer issue in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192698/how-to-solve-this-timer-issue-in-java)
- [Timing and Animation in Java](http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Helping presented solution by "Javascript is GOD", I do this, play a game at a specific time.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  boolean flag = true;
  while (flag) {
      new TimerDemo(30);
      game();
    }
}
```

Notice that the flag variable changes within the `game()`.